The Invariance of the Distribution of a Matrix
I'm currently stuck to the following statement.

Given $W\in\mathbb R^{p\times d}$ having i.i.d entries from $N(0,1/d)$, define $Q\in\mathbb R^{p\times p}$  as follows:
$$Q_{i,j} = \begin{cases}w_i^Tw_j& i\neq j \\
0& i=j.\end{cases}$$
where $w_i\in\mathbb R^d$ is the $i$th row vector of $W$, $i=1,\dots,p$.  Also, for $s\ge t\ge0$, define $N \times N$ matrix $A(s,t)$ as follows:
$$A(s,t) = \begin{bmatrix} sI_p+tQ & X^T/\sqrt{n} \\ 
X/\sqrt{n} & O_n\end{bmatrix},$$
where $N:=p+n$, and $X\in\mathbb R^{n \times p}$ is a random matrix and $O_n$ is a $n\times n$ zero matrix. Then, for $z\in\mathbb C$, we have the following properties
$$\begin{align} M_{1,n}(z,s,t) &= \frac{1}{p}\text{Tr}_{[1,p]}\Bigl\{(A(s,t) - zI_N)^{-1}\Bigr\} \\
m_{1,n}(z,s,t) &= \mathbb E \Bigl[(A(s,t) - zI_N)^{-1}_{1,1}\Bigr] = \mathbb E[M_{1,n}(z,s,t)] \\ M_{2,n}(z,s,t) &= \frac{1}{p}\text{Tr}_{[p+1,N]}\Bigl\{(A(s,t) - zI_N)^{-1}\Bigr\} \\ 
m_{2,n}(z,s,t) &= \mathbb E \Bigl[(A(s,t) - zI_N)^{-1}_{p+1,p+1}\Bigr] = \mathbb E[M_{2,n}(z,s,t)]
\end{align}$$
where $\text{Tr}_{[i,j]}(B)$ means trace of matrix $B$ from $i$th to $j$th diagonal elements.

What I don't understand is this explanation; The equalities in the 2nd and 4th line above follow by the invariance of the distribution of $A(s,t)$ under permutation of $[1,p]$ and $[p+1,N]$. That is, the rows and columns of $A$ within the permutation $[1,p]$ and $[p+1,N]$ are exchangeable, as well as those of $(A-zI)^{-1}$.
The matrix $(A-zI)$ can be written as
$$(A-zI) =  \begin{bmatrix} sI_p+tQ-zI_p & X^T/\sqrt{n} \\ 
X/\sqrt{n} & -zI_n\end{bmatrix},$$so, for the case of $[1,p]$, the block matrix of $i$th row/columns of $A-zI_N,i=1,\dots, p$  can be written as (using block matrix inverse)
$$(A-zI_N)^{-1}_{[1,p],[1,p]} := \begin{cases}\bigl\{\tilde Q-X^T(-zI_n)^{-1}X/n\bigr\}^{-1}\\ \\ \qquad \text{or} \\ \\ \tilde Q^{-1} + \tilde Q^{-1}X(-zI_n-X\tilde Q^{-1}X^T/n)^{-1}X^T\tilde Q^{-1}/n,\end{cases}$$ where $\tilde Q(z,s,t) := (s-z)I_p+tQ$. Although having both expression for the block matrix of $(A-zI_N)^{-1}$, I don't see the meaning of the invariance of the distribution, that is, how  the invariance of $A(s,t)$ under permutation $[1,p]$ leads to the invariance of distribution of $(A-zI)^{-1}$ under the same permutation?
Any comments about this question would be grateful. Thank you.
